# Does anyone have experience with IDW interpolation using Shepards method for functions with two parameters in Julia language?

Tags: julia, interpolation

My code is as follows:

```
using Plots

# Define the function to interpolate
function f(x, y)
    return x/2 + y/2
end

# Generate sample data
data = [[x, y, f(x, y)] for x in -5:0.5:0, y in -5:0.5:0]

# Define the function for 2D shepard's method inverse distance weighting interpolation
function shepard_idw(x::Float64, y::Float64, data::Matrix{Vector{Float64}}, p::Float64)
    n = size(data, 1)  # Number of data points
    weights = zeros(n)  # Initialize weights
    already_in_dataset = false
    # Calculate distances and weights using Shepard's method
    for i in 1:n
        distances = sqrt((x - data[i][1])^2 + (y - data[i][2])^2)
        if isapprox(distances, 0.0)
            interpolated_value = data[i][3]
            already_in_dataset = true
            break
            #weights[i] = 1.0  # If the point is exactly on a data point
        else
            weights[i] = 1.0 / distances^p  # Inverse distance weighted using Shepard's method
        end
    end
    
    if already_in_dataset
        return interpolated_value
    end
    # Normalize weights
    weights ./= sum(weights)
    
    # Calculate interpolated value using Shepard's method
    interpolated_value = sum(weights .* [point[3] for point in data])
    
    return interpolated_value
end

# Define range for visualization
x_range = -5:0.5:0
y_range = -5:0.5:0

# Create meshgrid for x and y values
x_vals = [x for x in x_range, y in y_range]
y_vals = [y for x in x_range, y in y_range]

# Compute z values for the interpolated function
z_vals_interpolated = [shepard_idw(x, y, data, 1.0) for (x, y) in zip(x_vals, y_vals)]

# Reshape the z values to match the grid shape
z_vals_interpolated_grid = reshape(z_vals_interpolated, length(x_range), length(y_range))

# Create surface plot for the interpolated function
surface_plot_interpolated = surface(x_range, y_range, z_vals_interpolated_grid, xlabel="X", ylabel="Y", zlabel="Z", title="Interpolated Function")

# Display the plot
display(surface_plot_interpolated)
savefig("11pt2.najt4-rangeDiffJENA-t1-interpolation-surface.png")  # Save plot as PNG file
```

Code compiles but the interpolated function is not as nearly good as it should be - I believe this might be due to dataset not being completelly appropriate for IDW (dense datasets with maximum and minimum of a function must be included). I have tried modifying parameter p, changing datasets, this is the closest I have gotten when it comes to interpolating. I wonder if anyone has any ideas/suggestions or sees if something is wrong with code?

As I have mentioned above, I have tried modifying parameter p, changing datasets, this is the closest I have gotten when it comes to interpolating.